# ConditionalPanel does not work as expected

Tags: r, shiny

I'm making an app for some tax calculations and want to show a `sliderInput` based on another user input (`input$use_fthbi`). Here's my code:

```
  checkboxInput(
    inputId = 'use_fthbi', 
    label = 'Use First-time Home Buyer Incentive?', 
    value = F
  ), 
  
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.use_fthbi == 'true'",
    sliderInput(
      inputId = 'fthbi', 
      label = 'FTHBI Percent', 
      min = 0, 
      max = 10, 
      value = 5,
      post = '%'  
    )
  )
```

I expect to see the `sliderInput` appear only when `use_fthbi` is selected but it shows up regardless. Checking or unchecking the input has no impact on the UI.

I've tried spelling true as `True` or even `T` both with and without quotes around it but with no change to the UI. Following the example here: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html

I've seen other similar questions on SO but they either relate to updating something using the `server` or just deal with typos.

[image]

[image]

**EDIT**

It appears to work with `radiobuttons`:

```
  radioButtons(
    inputId = 'use_fthbi', 
    label = 'Use First-time Home Buyer Incentive?', 
    choices = c('Yes', 'No'), 
    selected = 'No',
    inline = T
  ), 
  
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.use_fthbi == 'Yes'",
    sliderInput(
      inputId = 'fthbi', 
      label = 'FTHBI Percent', 
      min = 0, 
      max = 10, 
      value = 5,
      post = '%'  
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close. The trick is to not use any quotes around `true`:

```
checkboxInput(
    inputId = 'use_fthbi', 
    label = 'Use First-time Home Buyer Incentive?', 
    value = F
  ), 
  
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.use_fthbi == true",
    sliderInput(
      inputId = 'fthbi', 
      label = 'FTHBI Percent', 
      min = 0, 
      max = 10, 
      value = 5,
      post = '%'  
    )
  )
```

This works for me with `shiny` 1.5.0 and `R` 4.0.2

Comment: I tried it before but it didn't work somehow a restart got it all working fine! Thanks anyway!

Comment: Got any suggestions for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64418703/update-three-different-inputs-based-on-sum-of-values-r-shiny ? :)