# Update three different inputs based on sum of values R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, reactive

I have four user inputs in my ShinyApp such that:

1. The first input (`total_price`) is always present
2. Optional input for `rrsp` which allows users to input a value (max 35,000)
3. Optional input for `fthbi` which allows users to select a value up to 10%
4. Other payment for `cash` which allows user to input a value

In my code, `total_input` and `cash` are `numericInput`, `rrsp` and `fthbi` are `checkBoxInput` + `conditionalPanel`

`total_price` is independent of the other three. However, the other other three summed up and can not exceed 20% of `total_price` i.e. `rrsp + fthbi * total_price + cash <= total_price*0.2`. How can I achieve this - basically as any of the inputs change, the limits of the remaining inputs (in the order mentioned above) should change as well.

**CODE**

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(
    'My App'
  ), 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
      numericInput(
        inputId = 'total_price', 
        label = 'Total Price', 
        value = 200000,
        min = 200000
      ),
      
      # Use RRSP for down-payment
      checkboxInput(
        inputId = 'use_rrsp', 
        label = 'Use RRSP?', 
        value = F
      ), 
      
      # If using RRSP, select amount to use
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.use_rrsp == true",
        numericInput(
          inputId = 'rrsp', label = 'RRSP Amount?',value = 25000, min = 0, 35000
        )
      ),
      
      # Use first time home buyer incentive?
      checkboxInput(
        inputId = 'use_fthbi', 
        label = 'Use FTHBI?', 
        value = F
      ), 
      
      # If using FTHBI, select % to use
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.use_fthbi == true",
        sliderInput(
          inputId = 'fthbi', label = 'FTHBI Percent',
          step = 1, min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, post = '%'  
        )
      ),
      
      # Cash Downpayment
      numericInput(
        inputId = 'cash', label = 'Cash Payment', value = 0, min = 0, max = 40000
      )
    ), 
    mainPanel = mainPanel(
      textOutput('main_text')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$main_text <- renderText({
    sprintf('Sample Text')
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I've tried playing around with `updateSliderInput` and `reactiveUI` but haven't been successful..

**Update**
Here's the logic:

1. by default `rrsp` and `ftbhi` are not selected, so `cash` can be set to 20% of `total_price`
2. Once `rrsp` is selected, it should begin with a default value of 25000. The max. value for `rrsp` is 35000 which is less than 20% of the min. allowable `total_value`. If some value for `cash` is selected that would bring `rrsp` + `cash` > `total_price`, the `cash` value should be updated such taht the total is 20% max.
3. Once `ftbhi` is selected, the default value should be zero (updated code now). The max. value for this should be updated based on the `rrsp` value (if already selected) else it should be 10%.
4. `cash` should get updated as other values are selected, input.

Comment: Is it always `rrsp + fthbi * total_price + cash <= total_price*0.2` or does it depend on which optional inputs are selected? And can you please detail how the limits should be updated (e.g. the first one always so strict that the constraint is met, even if the selected value is over the limit?)

Comment: @starja I added some logic, hope that clarifies things.

Answer (score 0):

Aou are on the right track in using the `update*` functions. I am not going to implement the complete logic yet the snippet below should point you in the right direction:

```
# Basic usage
library("shiny")
library(shinyWidgets)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(
    'My App'
  ), 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel(
      numericInput(
        inputId = 'total_price', 
        label = 'Total Price', 
        value = 200000,
        min = 200000
      ),
      
      # Use RRSP for down-payment
      checkboxInput(
        inputId = 'use_rrsp', 
        label = 'Use RRSP?', 
        value = F
      ), 
      
      # If using RRSP, select amount to use
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.use_rrsp == true",
        numericInput(
          inputId = 'rrsp', label = 'RRSP Amount?',value = 25000, min = 0, 35000
        )
      ),
      
      # Use first time home buyer incentive?
      checkboxInput(
        inputId = 'use_fthbi', 
        label = 'Use FTHBI?', 
        value = F
      ), 
      
      # If using FTHBI, select % to use
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.use_fthbi == true",
        sliderInput(
          inputId = 'fthbi', label = 'FTHBI Percent',
          step = 1, min = 0, max = 10, value = 0, post = '%'  
        )
      ),
      
      # Cash Downpayment
      numericInput(
        inputId = 'cash', label = 'Cash Payment', value = 0, min = 0, max = 40000
      )
    ), 
    mainPanel = mainPanel(
      textOutput('main_text')
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  output$main_text <- renderText({
    sprintf('Sample Text')
  })
  
  
  observe({
    # check that the input exists, is not null etc. check ?req()
    req(input$cash)
    if(input$cash > 0)
      updateSliderInput(session = session,
                        inputId = 'fthbi',
                        max = round(40000 / input$cash))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Just wrap your update function inside of observe. However, you should be carefull that you do not implement a infinite loop. In this case it is an option to determine each value, safe it in reactiveValues and use these to update your inputs.